# Why does my algorthim for insertion sort return different values , when I use the same value in condition statement?

Tags: c++

# At first case I put the temp variable to condition statement in while loop#

```
  int tab[8]={0,1,7,8,7,6,5,2};
    int n=8;                
    int j;
    int temp;


    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        temp=tab[i];
        j=i-1;

        while(j>=0&&tab[j]>temp)
        {
            tab[j+1]=tab[j];
            --j;    
        }
        tab[j+1] = temp;

    }
```

And the resault that I get is :

```
0 1 7 8 7 6 5 2
0 1 2 5 6 7 7 8
```

But on the other hand when instead I use tab[i] in condition statement in while loop

```
for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    temp=tab[i];
    j=i-1;

    while(j>=0&&tab[j]>tab[i])
    {
        tab[j+1]=tab[j];
        --j;    
    }
    tab[j+1] = temp;

}
```

I get this result:

```
0 1 7 8 7 6 5 2
0 1 7 7 6 5 2 8
```

And I can't find any difference between passing these values and why it behaves like that.
I think that I am using the same values. 
It's mine first question on that page , be kind to me please, have a nice day

Comment: Why would someone create a screenshot of two lines of terminal output, upload the image and link it here instead of simply copy and pasting the text?

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore, i wanted to make temp and tab[i] being bold but all i got was ** tab[i]  **

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If `tab[j+1]=tab[j];` changes the index that was `i` in your loop condition, the loop condition changes. That's why `temp=tab[i];` is saved before entering the loop and `temp` used as the loop condition -- `temp` doesn't change, but the value in `tab[i]` can.

Comment: David C.Rankin thank you so much man

Comment: Glad to help. A lot of the algorithms that are heavy on array indexing may use temporary variables -- that you may be tempted to do away with -- but they are generally there for a necessary reason. As here, you look at `tab[i]` and see nothing messing with `i` in the loop, so you think "I can just do away with `temp` and slide `tab[i]` in it's place..." But there is a lot of other indexing going on with `tab[j]` that, while not immediately apparent, is really changing what is at `tab[i]` along the way. We've all scratched our heads at things like this at one point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Because in first iteration of `while` loop if `tab[j] > tab[i]`

`tab[j+1]=tab[j];` changes `tab[i]` to `tab[i - 1]`,

So essentially your whole program in second case is equivalent to this

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    int tab[8]={0,1,7,8,7,6,5,2};
    int n=8;                
    int j;
    int temp;


    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        temp=tab[i];
        j=i-1;

        if (tab[j]>tab[i])
        {
            tab[j+1]=tab[j];
            --j;    
        }
        tab[j+1] = temp;

    }

    for(auto&& a: tab) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }
}
```